# There is no sound when playing HTML5 AUDIO in IOS17

Tags: reactjs, html5-audio, ios17

```
export function AudioPlaying(audioUrl: string): ReactElement {
    const audioRef = useRef<HTMLAudioElement>();

    useEffect(() => {
        audioRef.current = new Audio(audioUrl);
    }, [audioUrl]);

    const onPlayAudio = () => {
        audioRef.current.play();
    };

    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={onPlayAudio}>click</button>
        </>
    );
}
```

The above example is simple, but the code with a similar behavior does not play when playing from IOS17. Is there a report on the issue?